# cannot figure out how to get each answer in incremental loop

Tags: java

I am coding a multiple choice quiz.

I have my questions as objects and each are contained in an array.
This is the code that I have.
Each object is names q1, q2 and so on.

```
for(int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) 
{
   System.out.println(questions[i]);
   choice = kb.nextLine();
   if(choice.equals(q1.getCorrectAns()))
   {
      correct++;
   }
}
```

The comparison works for the answer of question 1, but I don't know how to make the comparison change with each question.

Also I tried searching for how to ignore the case of user input, but the things I tried did not work. How can I achieve that?

Creation of the objects and the array

```
Question q1 = new Question("These are the rules that must be followed when writing a program.",
                                                                        "a. syntax", "b. punctuation", "c. key words", "d. operators", "a");
Question q2 = new Question("A group of statements are enclosed in __________.", 
                                                                        "a. brackets []", "b. parenthesis ()", "c. braces {}", "d. any of these", "c");
Question q3 = new Question("This is an if statement that appears inside another if statement",
                                                                        "a. nested if statement", "b. structured if statement", "c. tiered if statement", "d. dislodged if statement", "a");



Question[] questions = new Question[3];

questions[0] = q1;
questions[1] = q2;  
questions[2] = q3;
```

Here is the question object constructor

```
public Question(String question, String optionA, String optionB, String optionC, String optionD, String correctAns)
{
    this.question = question;
    this.optionA = optionA;
    this.optionB = optionB;
    this.optionC = optionC;
    this.optionD = optionD;
    this.correctAns = correctAns;
}
```

**EDIT**: My array only consists of the three questions. How can I print each one out, one time each, at random?

Comment: Can you show the `getCorrectAns` method?

Comment: You've created an array of questions, so you can create an array of answers to match those questions.

Comment: When you find yourself creating variables named `q1`, `q2`, etc - you should really use an array instead

Comment: I want to be able to access the answer field of the object from within the array

Comment: Share the code where you create `questions[]` and `q1,..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already iterating correctly over the questions when you do this: `System.out.println(questions[i]);` - you just need to do that for your answer comparison as well.

Specifically, instead of checking `if(choice.equals(q1.getCorrectAns()))`, check for `if(choice.equals(questions[i].getCorrectAns()))`

As a note, you may want to consider changing your question output to do something like `System.out.println(questions[i].getQuestion());`, so you don't need to override `Question.toString()` to only output the question.